# How to export data to csv which i got in Ajax success function on single click (its working if i do double click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is working on double click. How to get it worked on single click.

```
function downloadData(Id){
        var queryString="Id="+Id;
        $.ajax({
                url: '/val/order',
                dataType: "text",
                data: queryString,
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                contentType : 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8', 
                success : function(tableString) {
                    var csvContentArray = [];
                    csvContentArray.push(tableString);
                   $("#order").attr("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(csvContentArray.join("\n"))).attr("download", "Blind_Structure_Data.csv");
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is just a function.It can work on any event.Show how are you attaching this method to DOM?

Comment: The code you show us don't include the event subscribsion, can you add it ?

Comment: create file on server side and download it from client ajax.

Comment: I am calling this function from here. <a href="#" id="order" onclick="downloadData(5); ">download</a> and in tableString i am getting data like This 1,10,1500,3000,1000,1500,200,500, 2,10,2000,4000,1000,2000,500,1000, 3,10,3000,6000,1500,3000,500,1000,

Comment: on first click it seems it is contracting  this URL 

$("#order").attr("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(csvContentArray.join("\n"))).attr("download", "Blind_Structure_Data.csv");

and on second click it is downloading. I want to do it in single click.